# Why is MotionEvent.getx() not the same result in onTouchEvent and onDraw?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
private lateinit var lastEvent: MotionEvent
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
   ...
   Log.d("demo","ondraw lastEvent.x="+lastEvent.x+"  lastEvent.y="+lastEvent.y)
   Log.d("demo","ondraw lastEvent.rawX="+lastEvent.rawX+"  lastEvent.rawY="+lastEvent.rawY)
   ...
}

override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
   ...
   when (event.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            return true
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
            lastEvent = event
            Log.d("demo","onTouchEvent lastEvent.x="+lastEvent.x+"  lastEvent.y="+lastEvent.y)
        }
        else -> {
        }
    }
  ...
}
```

Why the lastEvent.x get different results。This problem is bothering me.

Place help me, thanks.

Comment: onTouchEvent lastEvent.x=434.95972  lastEvent.y=299.45508  
ondraw lastEvent.x=434.95972  lastEvent.y=761.4551
ondraw lastEvent.rawX=434.95972  lastEvent.rawY=761.4551

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, the method `onDraw()` is not being called as soon as you touch the view.

Add a call to `invalidate()` at the end of the method `onTouchEvent()` so that it will invoke the method `onDraw()` internally and draw at the same location.

Comment: This is my print log, the getx is equel,but gety() = getrawY.
onTouchEvent lastEvent.x=434.95972 lastEvent.y=299.45508 ondraw lastEvent.x=434.95972 lastEvent.y=761.4551 ondraw lastEvent.rawX=434.95972 lastEvent.rawY=761.455